# How to set the metadata dynamically to match state values in the app directory of Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In the `app` directory of Next.js `13`, I saw in the official documentation that they've abandoned the old head method in favor of using metadata, and I thought it was only available on page or layout.

I want to change the title based on the state value, how can I do that?
The object in the metadata is outside the component, so I can't reference it.

```js
import type { Metadata } from 'next';
 
export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Home',
  description: 'Welcome to Next.js',
};
 
export default function Page() {
  return '...';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by `state` you mean something similar to `useState`, it's not possible. Because `metadata` is for Server Components only, whereas `useState` can only be used in Client Components. The doc [says](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-metadata#config-based-metadata):

> The `metadata` object and `generateMetadata` function exports are only supported in Server Components.

For a normal page, you normally know what metadata to return, so the [`metadata`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-metadata#metadata-object) object should be enough. If the page is dynamic, there is [`generateMetadata`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-metadata#generatemetadata-function):

> Dynamic metadata depends on **dynamic information**, such as the current route parameters, external data, or `metadata` in parent segments, can be set by exporting a `generateMetadata` function that returns a Metadata object.

Find below an example of setting the title dynamically:

```js
// app/products/[id]/page.tsx

export async function generateMetadata({ params, searchParams }) {
  // read route params
  const id = params.id;

  // fetch data
  const product = await fetch(`/api/products/${id}`).then((res) => res.json());

  // return a dynamic title
  return {
    title: product.title,
  };
}

export default function Page() {
  return '...';
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be wrapped in a `try/catch`?

Comment: It could be, to play safe :)

Comment: but in this way, we are fetching the product details twice. As we need to fetch the product again inside the page. Or is there a way to fetch product details just once and pass it to both exports?

Comment: There is no such way as far as I know. And normally this isn't a problem since [Next.js will dedupe those requests and uses the cache](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#sharing-fetch-requests-between-server-components).

Comment: Is there a way to also add images using this?